# Function to transform the text after the window resizing too

Tags: javascript

I have a utilitarian function made to transform the paragraph. The function is working good. But I want to do it worked too after the window's browser resizing too. 
It was my initial code:

**Note:** 
What the function do, it doesn't matter. This function avoid a single word in the paragraph's last line but it could be anything that transform the text. The goal of my question is only to apply it on the resizing.

```
export const noMoreLonelyWords = (selector, numWords) => { 
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
      var textArray = elems[i].innerText.split(" ");
      var lastWords = textArray.splice(-numWords, numWords).join("&nbsp;");
      var textMinusLastWords = textArray.join(" ");
      elems[i].innerHTML = textMinusLastWords + " " + lastWords;
    }    
}
```

Then I did this change to try to apply it on the resizing too and it didn't work. See after the commentary line.

```
export const noMoreLonelyWords = (selector, numWords) => { 
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
      var textArray = elems[i].innerText.split(" ");
      var lastWords = textArray.splice(-numWords, numWords).join("&nbsp;");
      var textMinusLastWords = textArray.join(" ");
      elems[i].innerHTML = textMinusLastWords + " " + lastWords;
    }  

    // CODE CHANGES <--- 
    window.onresize = () => {
      noMoreLonelyWords(selector, numWords);
   }  
   //
}
```

Comment: At the moment the resize handler is only attached when the function `noMoreLonelyWords` has been run. I don't know your usage but pulling the `window.onresize = ...` statement outside of the function may provide the functionality you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your function to the `resize` event like this:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => noMoreLonelyWords(selector, numWords));
```

Resize events fire often when the user is dragging the window, so it's a good idea to debounce your function calls.

In this example, the callback is an anonymous function. You might want to extract it out such that you can remove the event listener again to prevent memory leaks.

**EDIT:** I might have misunderstood your question. Do you get any errors when using `window.onresize`? Remember that if you listen to events this way, you will overwrite previous listeners that used `window.onresize`